# Photoshop: Cutting path out of layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, mask, crop, clipping-mask

[image]

Having trouble cutting the path out from the above image. I managed to cut the outside with a layer mask, but when i do that now for this it crops just that area. Do I need to invert it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have mask and a path created, simply turn it into a selection via the **Paths Panel** (Window > Paths).

1. Select your path and navigate to the Paths Panel:

[image]

2. Right-click the shape path and select 'Make Selection...' in the drop-down menu:

[image]

3. Navigate back to the 'Layers Panel' and select the layer mask you wish to add to. Fill with black to mask out the image.